# Splitting string in 2 or more regex

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm trying to split a string into parts where a `,` `()` `spaces` are involved.

It's coming from a combo box item. It looks like this

**ComboBox Item**

```
(123456) LastName, FirstName MiddleName
```

And I want to separate it into parts

```
int employeeNumber = 123456
String lastName = LastName
String firstName = firstName
String middleName = middleName
```

So I tried this but can't get the result I want because it seems it's only splitting it by commas.

```
String facultyName = adviserJcbx.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String [] facultyNameSplit = facultyName.split(",");
        String facultyLastName = facultyNameSplit[0]; 
        String facultyFirstName = facultyNameSplit[1];
        //String facultyMiddleName = facultyNameSplit[2];
```

I get an error if I try something like `facultyName.split(",()\\s+");`

All these four variables will be used in a `CALLABLE` stored proc's WHERE clause like

```
SELECT id from table WHERE empNo = employeeNumber AND lName = lastName AND fName = firstName AND mName = middleName;
```

I hope you can help because I researched online but can't find any example where more characters are involved on split.

Also, is there any easier way to get an Id of an element in GUI element without having to create a stored procedure like the ones I'm creating

```
CALL getFacultId(?,?,?,?);
```

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

My goal is to get the Id of what is selected in combo box by splitting them and supplying it to the `getFacultyId(?,?,?,?)` stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex like this:

```
\(([^)]*)\)\s*([^,]+),\s*(\S+)\s*(\S*)
```

Sample Java code for that:

```
String input = "(123456) LastName, FirstName MiddleName";
String regex = "\\(([^)]*)\\)\\s*([^,]+),\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\S*)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("empNo = " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("lName = " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("fName = " + m.group(3));
    System.out.println("mName = " + m.group(4));
}
```

*Output*

```
empNo = 123456
lName = LastName
fName = FirstName
mName = MiddleName
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a regular expression rather than split:

```
Pattern facultyPattern = Pattern.compile("\((\\d+)\) (\\w+), (\\w+) (\\w+)");
Matcher facultyMatcher = facultyPattern.match(facultyString);
if (facultyMatcher.matches() {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(facultyMatcher.group(1));
    String lastName = facultyMatcher.group(2);
    String firstName = facultyMatcher.group(3);
    String middleName = facultyMatcher.group(4);
    ...
} else {
    // handle mismatch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `CONCAT` these four columns into format you mentioned:

```
SELECT id 
from table 
WHERE CONCAT('(', empNo, ') ', lName, ', ', fName, ' ', mName) = ?;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I've actually managed to get the concatenated string to the combo box. My problem now is how to split the concatenated string into parts so I can use it to the WHERE clause. I've added the screen shot in the description.